# How to fill list properties of objects from SQL while maintaining small result sets?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, mybatis

## Problem description

For a (PDF-)report in a Java application I query various data from a PostgreSQL 9.6 database. The data passed to the report also contains lists which in turn contain other lists. However overall the report does not contain that many values (number of values is somewhere in the hundreds).

To query the data I use a huge SQL statement with multiple joins (about 8) to also query the data for the lists and the lists in the lists. But naturally the joins cause a lot of rows to be duplicated in the output. E.g. the following query:

```sql
select *
from (values(1,'item A'), (2, 'item B')) items(id, label)
left join (values(1, 'subItem A1'), (1, 'subItem A2'), (1, 'subItem A3')) subitems(itemId, label) on items.id=subitems.itemId
left join (values(1, 'sub2Item A1'), (1, 'sub2Item A2'), (1, 'sub2Item A3')) subitems2(itemId, label) on items.id=subitems2.itemId
```

returns just 10 rows for 8 values, which is easy to work with. However one more join on another subitems-table with just 3 more values will already include 28 rows (for a total of 11 values):

```sql
select *
from (values(1,'item A'), (2, 'item B')) items(id, label)
left join (values(1, 'subItem A1'), (1, 'subItem A2'), (1, 'subItem A3')) subitems(itemId, label) on items.id=subitems.itemId
left join (values(1, 'sub2Item A1'), (1, 'sub2Item A2'), (1, 'sub2Item A3')) subitems2(itemId, label) on items.id=subitems2.itemId
left join (values(1, 'sub3Item A1'), (1, 'sub3Item A2'), (1, 'sub3Item A3')) subitems3(itemId, label) on items.id=subitems3.itemId
```

and the number of rows grows quickly with each join operation. In my account example the query I wrote in the meantime generates somewhere around half a million rows, just for an average sized report with only a couple of hundred of values. While building the lists from the query (I use MyBatis for that) works fine, it is slow, consumes a lot of bandwith and consumes lots of memory so that this actually ends up to be a problem.

## Ideas for solution

- One option would be to use MyBatis' "**nested select**" feature which allows me to automatically retrieve lists using N+1 queries. However some of the joins join on views which need to group and sum large tables which is slow and filling two lists with data from those views is much faster if the view is queried only once.
- Another possibility would be **perform some of the join operations in Java** by selecting the data from the different tables/views separately and then filling the object's lists from those data. While this would work it kind of ignores the power of SQL and I need to replicate features of SQL myself.
- A third possibility would be to simply ignore the table structure of SQL and **build hierarchical structures, e.g. using JSON**:

  ```sql
  select
    json_agg(jsonb_build_object(
          'id', items.id,
          'subA', subitems.list,
          'subB', subitems2.list,
          'subC', subitems3.list
  )) result
  from (values(1,'item A'), (2, 'item B')) items(id, label)
  left join (
    select itemId, json_agg(label) list
    from
    (values(1, 'subItem A1'), (1, 'subItem A2'), (1, 'subItem A3')) subitems(itemId, label)
    group by itemId
  ) subitems on items.id = subitems.itemId
  left join (
    select itemId, json_agg(label) list
    from
    (values(1, 'sub2Item A1'), (1, 'sub2Item A2'), (1, 'sub2Item A3')) subitems(itemId, label)
    group by itemId
  ) subitems2 on items.id = subitems2.itemId
  left join (
    select itemId, json_agg(label) list
    from
    (values(1, 'sub3Item A1'), (1, 'sub3Item A2'), (1, 'sub3Item A3')) subitems(itemId, label)
    group by itemId
  ) subitems3 on items.id = subitems3.itemId
  ```

  The later option returns:

  ```json
  [{
    "id": 1,
    "subA": ["subItem A1", "subItem A2", "subItem A3"],
    "subB": ["sub2Item A1", "sub2Item A2", "sub2Item A3"],
    "subC": ["sub3Item A1", "sub3Item A2", "sub3Item A3"]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "subA": null,
    "subB": null,
    "subC": null
  }]
  ```

  The JSON result is something that I could easily parse in Java again. This option looks most efficient to me because it completely eliminates the data duplication and it can be deserialized directly to a Java object which has already the right structure to work with. However it comes at the cost of slight readability penalty, because of all the `json_agg` and `jsonb_build_object` calls that need to be made.

## Question

I guess that I am not the first person running into this issue. So are there other options? Is there some "commonly accepted best practice" to deal with the problem? Is my analysis of the possible options correct?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you make some operations with your DBMS ?

If you generates over half a million row for an average sized report, i guess that you're retrieving some data and compute it in your Java Code.

You could make some views or aggregate tables to simplify your query.

Comment: No, I am not doing any computation in Java at all. The only thing that happens in Java is converting the tabular result into a tree object structure. However of course I could build the tree structure in the DBMS and that is exactly what my JSON-solution presented above does.